My SSIS project doesn't let me use Newtonsoft.json nuget package
I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I'm creating a SSIS project but I'm having an issue and it is when I install Newtonsoft.json nuget package inside my Script Component (because this is where I need to use it) and I close the Edit Script window and reopen, it its still installed but not recognized by compiler, as if it wasn't there.
¿What can I do? Thanks in advance.

When you close it, do you hit CANCEL?  Or Save?  You have to make sure you hit SAVE or all changes will be lost.
